# Navigation Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml

gostaria de uma ajuda quando abro meu Navigation Activity apos o login recebo ele assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Porém eu gostaria que ele já fosse chamado assim com uma das páginas marcadas tipo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_abertas"
            android:title="Consultas Abertas"
            android:visible="true" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fechadas"
            android:title="Consultas Fechadas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_medicos"
            android:title="Médicos" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Você já está carregando esse Fragment `Consultas Abertas`?

Comment: Então, sou novato em android, e me colocaram para fazer este projeto, então não sei muito como utilizar o navigation activity @LeonardoDias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua activity, está implementando `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, certo?

Então, você terá um método assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.consultas_abertas) {
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ConsultaAbertasFragment, name)
            .commit();
        }

        //Resto do código

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

O sistema irá veriricar qual id do menu foi clicado, e vai chamar o Fragment correspondente a ele, e o próprio sistema vai cuidar de selecionar ali no menu o Fragment que foi chamado.

O XML do seu Menu, deve estar mais ou menos assim:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/consultas_abertas"
            android:title="Consultas Abertas" />

        //Resto do código

    </group>
</menu>
```

E por último, no XML da sua Activity, você deve ter o FrameLayout aonde serão carregados os Fragments, referente a esse id `R.id.container`, exemplo:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Leonardo, então deverei criar um layout xml para cada um dos itens do menu?`.replace(R.id.container, ConsultaAbertasFragment, name)` e nessa parte será o container do xml da activity, o nome do layout, e esse name é o q ?

Comment: Não, no mesmo XML do menu vc coloca todos os items, vc já deve ter ele criado ai, o nome do XML é `activity_main_drawer`. Já o name é só um nome pro Fragment, não impacta em nada, por exemplo "fragment consultas"

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta e coloquei o `activity_main_drawer.xml` e é apenas isso que tem nela

Comment: É isso ai, ele já ta certo, cada item é um botão lá no menu, na hora de vc comparar o id, dentro do `onNavigationItemSelected`, vc usa `if (id == R.id.nav_abertas) {` Ai muda o Fragment que vai ser colocado no `FrameLayout`

Comment: estou colocando o seu codigo do `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ConsultaAbertasFragment, name)
            .commit();` porém na parte que ta escrito ConsultaAbertasFragment e na parte name não sei o que colocar (desculpa ser leigo no assunto)

Comment: No Lugar do ConsultaAbertasFragment, vc tem que colocar o nome do Fragment que vc criou, cada tela que abre através ali do menu, é um Fragment diferente, e o `name` pode colocar qualquer coisa, por exemplo: "consultas abertas fragment"

Comment: Então os itens que são criados no activity_main_drawer.xml são os fragment? ou são outros arquivos que são criados ?

Comment: Lá no `activity_main_drawer.xml` são só os botões do menu, ai cada botão vai abrir uma classe que extende Fragment respectiva aquele botão, por exemplo, o `R.id.nav_abertas` vai abrir o Fragment `ConsultaAbertasFragment`, já o `R.id.nav_fechadas` vai abrir o Fragment `ConsultasFechadasFragment`. Pra cada item do menu, vc tem que ter uma classe que extende Fragment

Comment: Valeu, ajudou muito cara desculpa tomar seu tempo

Comment: Imagina, sempre q precisar estamos ai